# Dark screen on Macbook Pro before disk decryption on boot

Tags: display, macbook-pro

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on my *Mac-Book Pro 15"*(late-2013) with the following specifications:

```
Memory: 8 GiB
Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-4750HQ CPU @ 2.00GHz × 8
Graphics: Intel® Haswell Mobile
OS type" 64-bit
```

Everything works fine, however (most of the time) when I boot the system, just before I enter my password to decrypt my disk, the built-in screen is very dark (low backlight brightness). But when I decrypt the disk, it lights up. Moreover, I don't experience this problem when connected to an external screen. Interestingly, I notice that only occasionally this problem goes away by its own.

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: So by "very dark" you mean low display backlight brightness? I never owned a Macbook, so I don't know much about these, but could there maybe be a BIOS/UEFI/firmware setting about startup brightness? Because when it asks for your hdd password, the Ubuntu operating system is not really loaded yet, just the most important components needed so far. I don't think there's enough graphics support at that point to really be able to control brightness, but again, these are only assumptions.

Comment: Thanks, @ByteCommander, for your  response. Yes, I meant the backlight brightness is very low (just enough for me to see the password field, by some efforts), but then the system finds what it needs, only after the disk is decrypted. and everything lights up)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was present only when Installing GNOME on top of an Ubuntu 16. When with the release of Ubuntu 18.0, Ubuntu switched to GNOME as the default DE, the problem seized from appearing.